# JavaScript objects - [] vs dot

Tags: javascript

What is the difference, if any, between these two assignments:

```
var foo = {};
foo['bar'] = "some value";
foo.baz = "some other value";

console.log(foo.bar)
=> "some value"
console.log(foo.baz)
=> "some other value"
```

Are they synonymous? I've noticed you can add keys with the [] syntax that are not valid property names.

```
foo['a space'] = "does not work";
console.log(foo.a space);
=> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

My reason for asking is that I've cooked up a little JS library for pseudo namespacing. It is written on the assumption that the above assignments are identical (ignoring the superset allowed when using [] syntax)

Comment: No technical difference for the first example. And as you stated the `[]` syntax allows for what would be invalid identifiers.

Comment: ...note that all JavaScript properties are strings, so whatever expression is given to `[]`, it will ultimately get the `toString()` treatment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`foo["bar"]` is equivalent to `foo.bar`, although `foo.bar` is easier to read in my opinion. As you already noticed the former syntax (`foo["bar"]`) allows you to use property names that are not valid identifiers. It also allows you to use dynamic property names:

```
var name = "bar";

foo[name] = 1;

console.log(foo["bar"]);
```

will output `1`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `.`, the property name is a literal identifier. When you use this in a program, you have to hard-code the property name.

When you use `[]`, the property name is an expression that is evaluated. It's not normally used with simple strings in quotes, because that's what `.` notation is for. But it's useful when you need to calculate the property, e.g.

```
console.log(foo["item"+i]);
```

This latter notation is also the only way to access properties that aren't identifiers. You can use any string as the property name this way.

Answer (score 2):

They are absolutely equivalents except that you can more possibilities with [] syntax for example

```
var bar = 'text';
foo[bar] = 'baz';
```

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent, but you cannot use the dot notation when the attribute-name contains a space (or other non-alphanumeric characters):

```
foo.a space // doesn't work
foo['a space'] // does
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is you can use variables in the second example however it's is always better to use dot notation like this

```
someObject.hello = ' hello john';
```

And the only time i use the other way is if i need to use a variable like this

```
var msg = 'goodbye';

someObject[msg] = 'goodbye john';
```

This would be the result

```
// someObject.hello => 'hello john'
// someObject.goodbye => 'goodbye john'
```

so use dot notation like `obj.some` and use `obj[myVar]` for variables

So the difference is you can use variables in the 2nd example

also if i done this

```
var myVar = 'test';

someObj.myVar = ' Hello Test ';
```

then this would be the result

```
// someObj.test => doesnt work - undefined
// someObj.myVar => ' Hello Test '
```